# Why is EVE heavily armed and trigger-happy?

Tags: wall-e

EVE robots are probes looking for fragile signs of returning life.  Earth conditions are unknown but there is little reason to expect anyone hostile.
Why equip her with such a strong weapon (melts through rock, raises nuclear-like mushroom clouds)?

And why program her to shoot immediately at anything that moves?  How is that a good way to find life? (She's looking for signs of plant life more than animals, but still.)

Comment: All of Earth's population was embarked on the Axiom. Including MI5. Tubby-Q was in the house and it seemed like a good idea at the time...

Comment: @dmckee - Actually there were a [considerable number of ships in the fleet](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106558/are-there-other-cruise-ships-in-wall-e-universe).

Comment: EVE is an iPhone 7000s, equipped with Siri-us-LE. She can give you directions, mark your calendar, identify plant life and vaporize 3 city blocks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### In-Universe

In the Director's commentary, Andrew Stanton described Eve as being the "*porsche*" of robots, containing ***every possible feature, regardless of the cost or potential for use.*** This would logically include the most advanced weaponry available.

> *"She's the highest, most expensive, **no-expense-spared kind of project
>   that the Buy'n'Large corporation could use to make a probe droid.**
>   She's so advanced that we don't even understand how she can float and
>   how these appendages can magnetically be close to one another and
>   things can separate, but it feels like it had a logic behind it"*

Since EVE's primary purpose is to travel to Earth and conduct a plant survey as part of the (classified) Operation Recolonise, it's reasonably clear that B'n'L intended for her to deal with *[any](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVIk9AvVXJw)* problems that she's likely to encounter. This would include anyone or anything that might prevent her from completing her vital mission or attempt to force her to reveal classified information. Potential foes could include humans from [other spaceships](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/BNL_Starliner), [rogue robots](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0096CUB2U) or simply things that [get in her way](https://youtu.be/L6cFeJQkntk?t=29s).

---

As to why she's so trigger-happy, this is covered in the crew commentary between Derek Thompson (story artist), Bill Wise (character supervisor) and Lindsey Collins (co-producer). Her hair-trigger response is apparently **a mixture of sensible precaution and nerves.**

> **Bill Wise:** [Laughs] *She **has** got a short fuse.*
>
> **Derek Thompson:** *Yeah, she's temperamental*
>
> **Lindsey Collins:** *Of course. **She's sent to a bunch of different worlds. She doesn't know where she's going. You don't know what's out
>   there.***
>
> **Derek Thompson:** ***If you were left in a tyre-yard, you'd be nervous.***

### Out of universe

The choice to arm Eve was evidently made by Pixar to enhance her clean lines, technical superiority and obvious femininity with a huge honking (and somewhat angular and masculine) cannon. From a dramatic perspective, this also serves to further distance her from the unarmed and wholly unassuming Wall-E unit that she encounters.

> EVE’s sleek, minimalist design contrasts with the brown, muddy, ruined
>   Earth. In this juxtaposition, **her simple cleanliness is exceptionally
>   beautiful — enhanced by the strength of her technical capabilities.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Concept Art: Eve Shooting Gun](https://collection.cooperhewitt.org/objects/136253029/)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

Comment: So having a gun is "masculine" and "enhances femininity" now? I think you missed the point of the characterisation: to obliterate gender biases like those that you evidently hold. Ironic given your avatar lol

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The juxtaposition of a masculine feature with an overall feminine portrayal helps to highlight her feminity. [Compare](http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/summer-glau-terminator-wallpaper-wallpaper-4.jpg) and [contrast](http://www.highwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/Summer-Glau-Ready-To-Shoot-With-Gun-1440x900.jpg)

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was this whole evil computer and it's hapless humans. EVE would perform nicely as an enforcer bot in case of an insurrection.

Comment: @MajorStackings - Possibly, but there's no real implication that the "Porter" robots wouldn't be perfectly capable of putting down a mutiny.

Comment: The line between data and code is ever defined by the currently running (and often buggy) code.  And, come on, girls with guns are just plain hot.